# Object following waypoint constantly rotates

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an object move from one point to another in a set path, however once the object reaches the first waypoint it constantly spins around instead of moving to the next point.

**Here is my code:**

```
public class Waypoint : MonoBehaviour {

   public Transform[] wayPoint = new Transform[9]; 
   int currentWayPoint = 0;

   float rotationSpeed = 6.0f;
   public float accelerate = 1.8f;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () 
   {
    wayPoint[0] = GameObject.Find("Waypoint1").transform;
    wayPoint[1] = GameObject.Find("Waypoint2").transform;
    wayPoint[2] = GameObject.Find("Waypoint3").transform;
    wayPoint[3] = GameObject.Find("Waypoint4").transform;
    wayPoint[4] = GameObject.Find("Waypoint5").transform;
    wayPoint[5] = GameObject.Find("Waypoint6").transform;
    wayPoint[6] = GameObject.Find("Waypoint7").transform;
    wayPoint[7] = GameObject.Find("Waypoint8").transform;
    wayPoint[8] = GameObject.Find("Waypoint9").transform;
   }

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () 
{
    if(currentWayPoint == 9)
    {
        Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        walk();
    }
}

void walk()
{
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(wayPoint[currentWayPoint].position - transform.position);
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, Time.deltaTime*rotationSpeed);

    Vector3 wayPointDirection = wayPoint[currentWayPoint].position - transform.position;
    float speedElement = Vector3.Dot(wayPointDirection.normalized, transform.forward);
    float speed = accelerate + speedElement;
    transform.Translate(0,0,Time.deltaTime*speed);
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
{
    if(collider.tag == "WayPoint")
        currentWayPoint++;  
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You need to increment currentWayPoint when you reach one. Check if the distance between the current waypoint and the script's transform are within a set distance (I usually use the speed).

```
if (Vector3.Distance(wayPoint[currentWayPoint].position, transform.position) < Time.deltaTime * speed)
  currentWayPoint++;
```

P.S. I also like seeing people flex their 3D math skills, but Unity has built in functions for a lot of what you're doing. (transform.LookAt(), then transform.Translate(Vector3.forward) * speed * Time.deltaTime)
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Vector3.html
http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Transform.html